# Connection between Taylor and strange expansion?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

### Background

Consider the following representation of a function:

$$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 e^{x} + a_2 e^{x^2} + a_3 e^{x^3} + \dots $$

Then,

$$f(0) = \sum_{i} a_i$$

Similarly,

$$ f'(x) = a_1 e^x + 2 a_2 x e^{x^2} + 3 a_3 x^2 e^{x^3} + \dots $$

$$\implies f'(0) = a_1$$

Or upon, again differentiating the equation we could have got:

$$ f''(x) = a_1 e^x + 2a_2 e^{x^2} + 4 a_2 x^2 e^{x^2} + \dots$$

Again, putting  $x = 0$:

$$ f''(0) = a_1 + 2a_2 $$

### Question

Is there some nice formula for $f'' ^n (0) $ ?

Comment: Not so fast. When you work with series, the first thing to verify is that they converge. So, you have to put some constraints on $\{ a_n\}$ to make everything rigorous, otherwise you can just take $a_n =1$ for evey $n$ and that would be infinite at 0.

Comment: Would it be fair game to ask for the constraints on ${a_n}$?

Comment: I mean, there are too many "variables" here that only you can know. For example, what regularity do you want $f$ to have? What should be its domain?

Comment: The root test shows that convergence occurs if $|x|<1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{1/n}<1$, and diverges for $|x|>1$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{1/n}>1$.